# Using INDEX & MATCH Function in a Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

Hi I need a bit of assistance getting this one started. I have a formula that works great on a worksheet, however I do not know how to convert that to a VBA code that will populate a combobox for me.

I had tried this and it populated the combobox with the N/A value and not the one I wanted:

```
 Dim ReturnVal As Variant

    ReturnVal = Evaluate("=INDEX('Teams'!B2:S21,MATCH(1,(""" & Me.Select_Team.Value & """ ='Teams'!B3:S3),0))")

    If Not IsError(ReturnVal) Then
        Me.Team_Leader.Value = ReturnVal
    Else
        Me.Team_Leader.Value = "N/A"
    End If
```

This is the formula that works on the excel worksheet.

Formula:

```
=INDEX(Teams!B2:S21,1,MATCH('Ticket Pools'!J6,Teams!B3:S3,0))
```

This searches names of Teams and brings up their allocated team leader from a range.

The Userform is called "Edit_Teams", on it there is a combobox "Team_leader" where I want the combobox to populate. The combobox is loaded so I just use:

"`Me.Team_Leader.Value = ReturnVal`"

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The ranges are not the same size.  I doubt the formula worked on the spread sheet.

Comment: I think you have an extra `1` on your index range:`'Teams'!B2:S21` should probably be: `'Teams'!B2:S2`

Comment: `ReturnVal = Evaluate("=INDEX('Teams'!B2:S2,MATCH(""" & Me.Select_Team.Value & """,'Teams'!B3:S3,0))")`

Comment: SCOTT YOU'RE A LEGEND!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ReturnVal = Evaluate("=INDEX('Teams'!B2:S2,MATCH(""" & Me.Select_Team.Value & """,'Teams'!B3:S3,0))")
```

– Scott Craner (c.f. comment)

This works (in case anyone needs to copy it)